# UTF-8 encoding error. Git pull wont apply fix

Tags: git, visual-studio, utf-8

On our site we had an UTF-8 encoding error. So we manually changed back all characters to their right ones. Now I did git pull without errors, but the characters are still wrong? I even did `git reset --hard origin/master` to point to the latest commit that have these changes. But they still remain.

I am starting to think that it might be something wrong with my editor `visual code` but in settings I have: `"files.encoding": "utf8"` and on site I have `<meta charset="UTF-8">`.

What can be causing this?

EDIT:

`Glömt Lösenord` becomes this:

[image]

Comment: can you describe more precisely the visible effects of your issue ?

Comment: @LeGEC please see edit

Comment: is `Glömt Lösenord` a value hard written in a html file ? (as opposed to : a value received from a database, and rendered in a template)

Comment: It is a hard coded html string fetched from a server. Like such: `$return .= '<a data-fancybox="iframe" data-src="/forgot-password" data-type="iframe" href="javascript:;">GlÃ¶mt lÃ¶senord?</a>';` Here you can see the error! But the commit I fetched should fix it to: `$return .= '<a data-fancybox="iframe" data-src="/forgot-password" data-type="iframe" href="javascript:;">Glömt Lösenord?</a>';` But it does not!

Comment: Have you checked that the file containing that text is correctly encoded? Git has no notion of encoding and treats all text files as "lines" of bytes so most likely a text editor wrote the wrong bytes into the file.

Comment: Also make sure you are actually inspecting the bytes because many editors will interpret the file contents in order to guess the encoding, so bringing the file up in an editor will in many cases look entirely correct, whereas a tool that actually uses the encoding it is supposed to will get the wrong characters.

Comment: All my files should be encoded. Since vstudios is set to `"files.encoding": "utf8"`. But how do I do to check certain files if they are encoded?

Comment: Create a new utf8 file with that text, inspect the bytes using a hex editor or similar, then inspect the bytes of the problematic file.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I did: `file -bi login.php` and got: `text/x-php; charset=utf-8`

Comment: Does the file contain a bom?

Comment: I am not sure how to check. I did: `/usr/bin/printf login.php | file -`and got: `/dev/stdin: ASCII text, with no line terminators`

Answer (score 2):

You can inspect the contents of file stored in git with the following command:

```
git cat-file -p <commit>:<path> | xxd -g1
```

There is no transformation in the command so it should always accurately show what is the content.

The `xxd` utility is bundled with Git for windows fir windows, in Linux distributions it can be in own packet or part of `vim` packet. You could also try `od` command from `coreutils` but it's output seems less convenient to read.

The "Glömt Lösenord" should look like:

```
echo Glömt Lösenord|xxd -g1
0000000: 47 6c c3 b6 6d 74 20 4c c3 b6 73 65 6e 6f 72 64  Gl..mt L..senord
0000010: 0a
```